# angularjs ng-repeat each item getting wrapped with copy of parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've only been using angularjs for a day so warning this may be a dumb question!

I have set of divs which display fine if I use the following:

```
<div class="numbers">
    <div ng-class="classes[0]">0</div>
    <div ng-class="classes[1]">1</div>
    <div ng-class="classes[2]">2</div>
    <div ng-class="classes[3]">3</div>
    <div ng-class="classes[4]">4</div>
    <div ng-class="classes[5]">5</div>
</div>
```

..but I thought that it would be better to use a loop so I tried:

```
<div class="numbers" ng-repeat="class in classes">
    <div ng-class="class">{{$index}}</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when using the ng-repeat each of the repeated items seems to get wrapped with its parent div which forces the width too wide and stops each number floating left.

Here it is on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/alanbeech/BLBJq/19/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `ng-repeat` directive on inner div tag

```
<div class="numbers" >
    <div ng-repeat="class in classes" ng-class="class">{{$index}}</div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/BLBJq/21/

Comment: Why you want to add it to the parent? This is syntax for ngClass directive.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this helped me too. For some reason I thought ng-repeat was supposed to be on the outer element rather than the inner. However, it makes sense that it should be in the inner element that needs to be repeated